# Azure ML: finding the very similar client/payer

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I am very new to Azure Machine Learning and Machine Learning also.

Let's say I have a list of some input variables {a1, a2, .. an} that define client (payer). The objective is to find very similar Payers based on these variables. And afterwards using this Azure service and display them in some table.

Can we use Azurue for this? Which algorithm is more likely to use?

Answer (score 1):

First you should figure out *how* you want to determine if two payers are similar. I suggest looking for a model for this in the are of Data Science and Machine Learning, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning. It doesn't have anything to do with Azure specifically. If you find a model/algorithm that works for you, implement that in some tool (I suggest R (https://www.rstudio.com/) but there are other options) or you can play around with it as an [Experiment in Azure ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-walkthrough-3-create-new-experiment).

Once you have your R script (or Python) you can *operationalize* that with Azure ML and use it in your Web App or LOB solution.

Comment: On our first step we want something to be shown very fast (it should be small pilot for demonstration). Later we could make our algorithm more sophisticated and use R/Python (which I have never used before). So for now we are very interested if there existing algorithms in Azure already implemented so we do not need to write the code (R/Python)?

Comment: Without knowing the basics of Data Science and machine learning it may be hard to do something that is both quick to implement _and_ shows something that is relevant. For your case I would try something very basic like the calculating the euclidian distance between vectors where each vector is a payer and the coordinates are the features you wish to correlate with (a1, a2,...). It's an expensive calculation because you have to match every payer against every other and then rank them based on the distance. There are optimizations here of course, but for a pilot it should be good enough.